# What is the difference between Ishta Deva and Aradhya Deva?

Tags: gods

Recently I've come across something that Ishta Devata and Aradhya Devata are different things.

When we have a devata as Ishta, we experience 5 signs like tears coming from eyes is one of them.
(I don't remember the others)

If we like some other god and don't get the 5 signs whenever something is going on about that deity, then the god is our Aradhya deva.

So, I want to know the difference between them and what are the signs we experience in each case?

**There is one more concept of Upasaya Devata. It is also very well related to this.(Somebody from this site told me earlier)
So, if anyone knows, please throw some light on this term.**